# Class/entities desing. User class and it's subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design

I would like to know what's your opinion on how to design sth like this.

I have a few kinds of users let's say they are called **A**,**B**,**C**.
They all can be subclasses of class **User**.
(They all will have different kind's of permissions that will allow them to read / write / enter certain pages of application.)

How should I design those calasses (**A**, **B**, **C** with/without superclass **User**) and tables in DB so they will work well in my application.

I'm writting in **JEE** with **JSF**. I'm reading about design patterns, but I don't know how to implement them with given  **DB** tables.

(e.g. How i will map the relationship beetween a abstract class User and it's subclasses in DB)

I'm using plain JPA.

Comment: This problem is unrelated to JSF at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, are you sure you have the correct overall class design? In many situations, a user may be a "User" today, but may later be promoted to be an "Administrator". This indicates that the user is playing a role, which is time constrained. If that is the case, inheritance is not the correct modelling technique. Peter Coad is the guru in this area - try Googling on his name.

Mapping object graphs to relational database tables is well-trodden territory. There are three main methods - one table per class hierarchy; one table per concrete class and one table per class (both abstract and concrete). No method is perfect - they all have tradeoffs. It is quite common for multiple mapping strategies to be used in the same database. Again, Google is your friend.